# Why my Qt app request msvcp120d.dll on a computer but not mine

Tags: c++, qt, dll, deployment

I did an application with Qt5.5, wich use open cv.
It works, so now I want to deploy it on several computers.

On the first PC (PC1), it works too : I copied the dll of Qt and open cv and add the paths in the environment variables. I copied a folder with my application, some dll and datas (images).

On the second PC (PC2), I did the same, but I can't open the application. I have the error "msvcp120d.dll is missing..".

- I compiled my app in release mode.
- On my PC and PC1 I moved msvcp120d.dll on the desk, and the app don't request it.
- Do you know why the app asks a debug dll?
- I soon installed the redistribuables packages visual C++ (x64 and x86) on PC2, but it doesn't install msvcp120d.dll.

Do you have an other idea?
thanks'

Answer (score 2):

It seems like some of the libraries that you are using is linking against a Debug CRT library (indicated by the trailing d in "msvcp120d.dll"). Those aren't redistributable, and are only available on systems, where Visual Studio is installed.

I would recommend to use dependency walker to find out which dlls/libraries that need the debug version and then recompile them as release configuration.

Comment: I notice that the app don't works if there is not the debug lib of opencv, so it's probably this.
However I comment the debug's lib in the qmake.

So I don't know why it request this..?

Comment: (I have run the qmake after and I let the release libs of opencv)